# projection not working with find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I'd like to exclude some fields by query,. Im using nodejs

```
public async getDoc() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.database.collection('users').find({email: "value3"}, {password: 0}).toArray((err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        })
    }
```

but in the result set I keep getting password field..

Comment: Use a projection document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Projection doesn't work with the new nodejs mongodb driver... Instead you will have to use [**`.project()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) cursor method here

```
this.database.collection('users')
  .find({ "email": "value3" })
  .project({ "password": 0 })
  .toArray();
```

Comment: Project is the right way to use. But It's not true that projection options doesn't work. It's just because the code of the author doesn't pass the right arguments for the otions.

Comment: `query failed: Unsupported projection option: projection: { password: 1.0 }` please test and then comment

Comment: please check your version of mongodb. projection is only available on version > 3. use `fields` instead if your mongodb version < 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use **fields** object as 2nd parameter in find method with all fields in that object which you want to get exluding password.

Do it like this:

```
find({email: "value3"}, {fields: {all_other_fields...: 1}})
```

You can also try **{fields: {password: 0}}** as well but I haven't tried it myself that's why I'm not sure that it'll work.

Comment: for version >3. `fields` is deprecated. You should you `projection` instead.