# Node.js + MongoDB - findOne() return one field not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why can I not be able to return only one field using "findOne()"? In the code below, all fields are returned. I also tried "find()", but still not working. Can someone tell me whether I made a mistake or what?

In this case, I want to return only "info" field

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient
...
db_main.collection('info').findOne({ _id: '123456789' }, { info: 1 }, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
})
```

The document look something like this:

```
_id: '123456789',
title: 'I love title',
content: 'content here',
info: {
    date: '1/1/2018',
    user: 'username'
}
```

Comment: Projection doesn't work with the new node mongodb driver... Instead you have to use `.project()` cursor method here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732527/projection-not-working-with-find-query/51732851#51732851

Comment: You need to check others status also

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are not using the projection option:

{projection: { info: true }}

The way you are doing

{info:1}

It means you are requesting to use an index on info (if it exist)

Comment: Docs for findOne `options`: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne