# MongoDB Node.js client projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, projection

I know this is probably an obvious question, but I am new to Mongo, and cannot find what I am doing wrong in looking through the documentation and examples... I am trying to query a list of records in mongo pulling out a specific field value from each of them, and I currently have.

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'TestDB';
let db = null;
let books = null;


// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Connection Failed")
  }
  db = client.db(dbName);
  books = db.collection('books')
  books.find( {}, { Name:1 } ).toArray().then(console.log)
});
```

But it prints out

```
[ { _id: 5b5fae79252d63309c908522,
    Name: 'TestBook',
    chapters: { '1': [Object] } } ]
```

Instead of

```
[ {Name: 'TestBook'} ]
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732527/projection-not-working-with-find-query/51732851#51732851

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to provide `projection` in the options parameter to get only the field `name`:

```
books.find({}, { projection: { Name:1 }})
     .toArray()
     .then(console.log)
```

Actually, `find` takes 2 parameters, the first one is the criteria for query and the second one includes some options. You can check the supported fields for options here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find

Updated: For `mongodb` package version < 3.0. Use `fields` instead of `projection`: `books.find({}, { fields: { Name:1 }})`