# Mongo NodeJS project() is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to exclude some attributes from the result. I read the specification: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/ - I need to use `project` function. So I chained this call but the code starts failing. The code worked fine without `.project({ auth: 0, prefs: 0, consent: 0 })`. Where is the issue? I found this answer which looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732851/1639556.

package.json

```
"mongodb": "^3.4.1",
```

Lambda

```
exports.handler = (payload, context, callback) => {
    const userId = payload.pathParameters.userId;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;   
    mongo.connectToDatabase()
        .then(db => {
            return findUser(db, userId);
        })
        .then(user => {
            console.log("User fetched");
        })
};

function findUser(dbClient, userId) {
    return dbClient.db()
        .collection("users")
        .findOne({ "_id": userId })
        .project({ auth: 0, prefs: 0, consent: 0 })
        .then(doc => { return doc; });
}
```

Error

```
2020-01-28T11:52:34.555Z        0701f485-3770-1f43-f838-4baec8377293    INFO    Request failed TypeError: dbClient.db(...).collection(...).findOne(...).project is not a function
at findUser (/var/task/src/handlers/users/getUser.js:41:10)
at mongo.connectToDatabase.then.db (/var/task/src/handlers/users/getUser.js:19:20)
```

PS I am curious if the projection is done at client side or server side. It is confusing to me that the `project` function is AFTER the `find` call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.project()` is a cursor function, so while you can use it on cursor methods, `findOne` does not return a cursor. What you can do is use the `project` as a query option.

In the documentation you linked theres an example of how to use it, in the follow case:

```
db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1, instock: { $slice: -1 } } )
```

The projection option is `{ item: 1, status: 1, instock: { $slice: -1 } }`.

So in your case you'll need to change your code to:

```
return dbClient.db()
    .collection("users")
    .findOne({ "_id": userId }, { auth: 0, prefs: 0, consent: 0 })
    .then(doc => { return doc; });
```

Or in case your using version 3+ of the Mongod nodejs driver change into:

```
return dbClient.db()
    .collection("users")
    .findOne({ "_id": userId }, {projection: { auth: 0, prefs: 0, consent: 0 }})
    .then(doc => { return doc; });
```

Comment: Hmm, this is contradicting to the documentation. And I found some answer where an author said this is an obsolete way. But I will give it a try

Comment: It actually works. Is the Mongo documentation wrong?

Comment: No, the Mongo documentation is for Mongo shell, you're using nodejs mongo driver which (rarely but sometimes) has different syntax.

Comment: I have selected NodeJS checkbox so it shows NodeJS syntax. 
const cursor = db.collection('inventory')
  .find({
    status: 'A'
  })
  .project({ item: 1, status: 1 });

Answer (score 4):

`project()` is only a function of the `find()` operation. It doesn't work with `findOne()` (as of mongoDB Node.js driver 3.6.0) and has to be passed in the options for that call. That's why the accepted answer works, but you've seen the `project()` function elsewhere.

The mongo documentation here only shows the `.project()` function after a `find()` call: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/project

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't use `.project()` after `findOne()` – but you can use it after `find()` – is that:

- `find()` returns a cursor, while
- `findOne()` returns the direct result, maybe an ordinary *document* object, which apparently don't have a `.project()` method.

So the solution is the same as previous answers: add an `{projection: ...}` argument to `findOne()`.